# after call reloadData() in swift uiTableView, old items remaining and new ones not shown

Tags: uitableview, swift3, reloaddata

I have a `TableView` in a `TabBar` that its data is got from server. After data loaded, I call `reloadData()` and all items are shown in first time. When user change tab of `TabBar` and return to current tab, items of `TableView` should be updated. but when I call `reloadData()` from second time old data is not removed an new data is not shown.

my code is :

```
if response.result.isSuccess { // Response is success

    if let estateFileResponse: EstateFileResponse = response.result.value { // Response is type of EstateFileResponse

        // Dismiss loader
        ShowHUD.sharedInstance.dismiss()

        // Append estateFile items to items list
        if estateFileResponse.estateFileList.count > 0 {

            self.items = estateFileResponse.estateFileList

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

This code only worked for the first time.

Comment: call all methods in viewWillAppear instead of viewDidLoad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to reload data synchronously

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```